# Descriptive Statistics in r comparing groups

Tags: r, statistics, comparison, categorical-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   200005 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ ID                                   : chr  "A16000" "A17000" "A17000" "A17000" "A18000"...
 $ Date                                 : Date, format: "2018-04-10" "2017-03-21" "2017-04-22" "2017-05-09" ...
 $ Educ                                 : num  0 1 0 0 1 NA NA 1 NA NA ...
 $ Returned                             : num  0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Burrowed                             : num  7 45 10 10 ...
 $ Freq                                 : num  1 10 10 2 ...
 $ Grp                                  : chr  NA "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "A" ...
```

and I want to find some descriptive statistics answers using it but I don't know what would be the best codes. I want to know: 1: does group A Return more than Group B? 2: Do customers with higher Freq burrow more? 3: Are customers with 10 or higher Freq more likely to have Educ?

I have tried using different tables, but they bring back long strings of values I can't make heads or tails of. Example of what I've tried:

```
#Comparison of returns by Groups
xtabs(~df$Returned+df$Grp,data=df)
rowPerc(xtabs(~df$Returned+df$Grp,data=df)) #numerical summary of variable
bargraph(~df$Grp,groups=df$Returned,data=df,type="percent") #graphical summary of variable
favstats(~df$Grp|df$Returned,data=df) #numerical summary of variable
bwplot(df$Returned~df$Grp,data=df)
```

But no matter what it just spits out a whole set that has like 200 rows which is not what i want and looks something like this:

```
  A        B                                   C    D     E                        F                    G
  0      21649                                 3 39218   477                      55                    87
  1        671                                 0  1491    22                       2                     0
  2        527                                 0   742     7                       1                     0
  3        328                                 0   410     1                       0                     0
  4        227                                 0   236     4                       1                     0
  5        340                                 0   395     1                       0                     0
  6        160                                 0   165     1                       1                     3
  7        117                                 0   146     1                       0                     0
  8        118                                 0   181     1                       0                     0
```

And continue for like 20 rows? What would be a better way of comparing this data and answering the questions?

I have also tried:

```
df_tidy <- df %>%

group_by(df$Group) %>%

dplyr::summarise(sum_collected = sum(df$Returned), na.rm = TRUE)



ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = df$Group, y = sum_collected)) +

geom_col()
```

But it just returns me this error: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): x Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

and the dataframe looks like:

```
df$Group\ sum_collected na.rm`

<chr> <dbl> <lgl>

1 A NA TRUE

2 B NA TRUE

3 C NA TRUE

4 D NA TRUE

5 E NA TRUE

6 F NA TRUE

7 NA NA TRUE
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the data you are showing us. Numeric columns are listed as numeric, but quoted as character strings. You cannot compute statistics on numbers stored as characters.

Comment: sorry thats my mistake i originally had the data as character but changed to as.numeric and updated but forgot to change the quotes. the data is numeric except for the group variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of going on here and it is extremely difficult to say where you struggle and why your return does not meet your expectation. There are also some issues with your code/code fragments that suggest reading up on the functions, parameters, etc.

Conceptually, you have 200k observations and your different groupings/questions will result in "many" summary results. Thus, you may have to "dive deeper" (and filter or transform your data) to get to the answer you are looking for.

Last but not least "best code" is definitely dependent on the eye of the beholder.

To get you started, the following might help.

P.S. I stick to the `{tidyverse}` set of packages, as I have the impression that it might be easier to handle, if you are new to the `R-ecosystem`.

**data**

Please provide your data as reproducible example. There will be many helping hands, if the data can be readily copied/reproduced for the problem.

I truncate/complement your example to 5 entries per variable. Please check that I added a date and changed the grouping.

```
df <- data.frame(
      ID = c("A16000", "A17000", "A17000", "A17000", "A18000")
    , Date = c("2018-04-10", "2017-03-21", "2017-04-22", "2017-05-09", "2018-03-17")
    , Educ = c(0, 1, 0, 0, NA)
    , Returned = c(0, 0, 3, 0, 5)
    , Burrowed = c(7, 45, 10, 10, 15)
    , Freq = c(1, 10, 10, 2, 3)
    , Grp = c(NA, "A", "A", "B", "B") 
)
```

**1: does group A Return more than Group B?**

Your code idea will get you quite some way. However, please read up on `{tidyverse}` and when/how to use `dplyr::...` or not. Also check your functions re syntax, commas, and closing parantheses.

Obviously, there might be more than Group A and B (not clear from the example). Since, the data came with a NA for an entry, I leave it there.
Thus, truncate to tailor the data frame to your problem.

```
library(dplyr)

df_tidy <- df %>%
##-------- truncate - aka filter to what you are interested in
    filter(Grp %in% c("A", "B")) %>%

##--------- group and summarise as given
    group_by(Grp) %>%
    summarise(sum_collected = sum(Returned, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This yields

```
> df_tidy
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Grp   sum_collected
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 A                 3
2 B                 5
```

This tibble only gives you the 2 groups you are interested in and you can judge whether A or B collects more on returns.

Plotting a barchart with "tidy" data frame gets simple (and does not come with the NAs, and misplaced logical checks.

For this read up `{ggplot2}`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df_tidy, mapping = aes(x = Grp, y = sum_collected)) +
  geom_col()
```

You can "beautify" this simple plot with annotations, themes, etc. But in principle it gives you the answer like the summary table.

**2: Do customers with higher Freq burrow more?**

This can be approached in different ways. With the limited data, let's go for a visual inspection, i.e. plot `burrow` over `frequency` by creating a scatterplot.

Note: the "example" data is sparse, thus it is a bit academic. But with your 200k data rows, you should be able to see the pattern more clearly.
For here I add a line layer to "give some pattern".

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Freq, y = Burrowed)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

This yields:
[image: simple scatter plot for visual interpretation]

For the example data: burrow increases with increasing frequency (while we observe a drop for freq 10 that might be an outlier when checking 200k data points).

Obviously, you can follow the pattern of the first question. (i) define what is "higher" frequencies and introduce another grouping/binning variable labelling the frequencies as HIGH and LOW. (ii) filter, and (iii) summarise (and plot a barchart).

**3: Are customers with 10 or higher Freq more likely to have Educ?**

Apply what you learnt from the previous 2 questions to this use case.

Comment: should the df_tidy only have 1 obs of 1 var?? cause i tried and it just gave me:                  > df_tidy
  sum_collected
1             8

Comment: Cryena, if you copy and use the code I worked on with the example data set I constructed (that emulates your data) you will get the results show in the answer. To be frank I have no idea how/why calling the object `df_tidy` would return `sum_collected 1 8`. Can you confirm that you used the dataframe `df` that I generate above?